# DensityPlot3D in cylindrical coordinates

Tags: plotting

How to easily plot a function `T[r,\[CurlyPhi],z]`   given in cylindrical coordinates similar to `DensityPlot3D` in cartesian coordinates?

Thanks

Comment: Couldn't you just use `DensityPlot3D` on `T[Sqrt[x^2 + y^2], ArcTan[x, y], z]`?

Comment: In principle yes, but I tried to avoid backtransformation of an NDSolve-problem in cylindrical coordinates.